# Fastest way to create a new dataframe based on a value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataframe that I need to break into chunks based on values in one of the columns. The way I am doing it works, but for large dataframes the single line below makes up about 70% of the entire time my code takes to run. Is there a faster way to achieve the same result?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create large dataframe
n = 100000000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(n).reshape(int(n/4),4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])

# split off data based on some criteria
# this takes approx 0.4s
df2 = df[df["a"] %10 == 0]
```

Comment: For this particular example, you can just define `df` with the correct data. But assuming you get your `df` in a more complicated way, I'm pretty sure this is the fastest way to filter it. Is 0.4s an issue?

Comment: Yes, this is just a simplified version for example's sake. The time is an issue because I have to do the operation on many occasions, so any improvement would help, but maybe it's not possible.

Comment: Well, now it's a question of which operation. If it's the same one, you can cash the result. If it's the same one, but with a different column/value, you can precompute it once and reuse it (I guess it's also cashing). But filtering 25mil rows, well it's as fast as it gets